# Return type of async method

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, return-type

Amazingly Typescript can give the return type of a function or a class method with `ReturnType<>` as in:

```
class Foo{
    bar(){ return {one:1, two:2};}
}

type  typeBar = ReturnType<Foo['bar']>;
```

However, if the method is async, is it possible to get the type of the resolved promise?

```
class Foo{
    async asyncBar() { return new Promise((resolve) => resolve({ one: 1, two: 2 }));}
}
type  typeBar = ReturnType<Foo['asyncBar']>; // the type here is Promise
```

So what would be the operator(s) to get `{one:number, two:number}` from `Foo['asyncBar']`?

Comment: Should the type not be just Promise? Do you mean to get the expected type of the resolved promise? Edit: I guess not, but not an expert, I am awaiting responses

Comment: @Osakr is right, the way you define `asyncBar` the type will be `Promise<{}>` and that is correct as that is the return of the function. What do you expect `typebar` to be ? `Promise<{one:number, two:number}>` or do you just want `{one:number, two:number}`. We can get either one but you need to provide more info :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, yep, I want {one:number, two:number}, the type of the resolved promise

Comment: You can unpack a promise type with `type Unpack<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : never`

Comment: @IngoBürk that sounds like an answer to me (or close to one), why put it where is should be :)

Comment: I'm on mobile where I can't test it, which I like to do before posting an answer. But alright, I'll post it :-)

Comment: @IngoBürk I test in the playground when on a mobile device :) If you switch to desktop site and use a coder keyboard it's usable ;)

Comment: Yeah, I don't have any of that. Hoping the recent announcement by Microsoft will include a better playground too... :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a type like

```
type Unpack<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T;
```

and then use

```
class Foo {
    async asyncBar() { return new Promise<{one:1, two:2}>((resolve) => resolve({ one: 1, two: 2 }));}
}

type Unpack<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T;
type typeBar = Unpack<ReturnType<Foo["asyncBar"]>>;
```

Comment: Since this was answered, TypeScript 4.5 [introduced](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements) the `Awaited<T>` utility type that can be used instead of `Unpack<T>` that is used in this answer.